# How do i retrieve their timestamp from an email

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

Writing a small script that pulls messages with a label and outputs the subject to a Slack channel.

I've gotten it down ( customized to from someone ) but need further help on where to get the time from.

```
/* Credit: gist.github.com/andrewmwilson */

function sendEmailsToSlack() {
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('!urgent');
    var messages = [];
    var threads = label.getThreads();

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        messages = messages.concat(threads[i].getMessages())
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var message = messages[i];
        Logger.log(message);

        var output = '*State Change Detected*';
      output += '\n*subject:* ' + message.getSubject();
        Logger.log(output);
```

Comment: Use the internalDate property of message

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`getDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate()) method on a message:

```
var message = messages[0]; // Get first message
Logger.log(message.getDate()); // Log date and time of the message
```